# I want to get clientWidth of div element if it changes during render

Tags: reactjs

I don't have access to sidebar `div` element because of `microfrontend`. I want to catch html renders during siderbar clientWidth changes. How can i access it.

Here are example code:

```
import { Box, BoxProps, HStack } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface Props extends BoxProps {
    leftActions?: React.ReactNode[];
    rightActions?: React.ReactNode[];
}

export const FormFooter = ({ leftActions, rightActions, ...props }: Props) => {
    const [sidebarWidth, setSidebarWidth] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const sidebarWidth = document?.querySelector<any>('.css-ygpt8u')?.clientWidth;

        console.log('sidebarWidth', sidebarWidth);
    }, [document]);

    return (
        <Box
            display={'flex'}
            justifyContent={'space-between'}
            {...props}
            width={`calc(100vw - 460px)`}
            right="84px"
            backgroundColor="white"
        >
            <HStack key="form-left">{leftActions?.map((element) => element)}</HStack>
            <HStack key="form-right">{rightActions?.map((element) => element)}</HStack>
        </Box>
    );
};
```

I tried to pass document inside array of useEffect but it gives me undefined.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the dependency of typeof document instead of document alone.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    Const clientWidth=document.getElementById(“someId”).clientWidth
},[typeof document])
```

Another solution is to use Refs on the sidebar div and its client width just as you do it with document. The difference is that refs directly change the Dom.